# Installation using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

How can I install a list of executable files in sequence, having multistep installation? Every file has different steps for its installation, for example, I need to click on License agreement ("I agree"),"Finish" etc. Is it possible to do step using python code?
And to detect the status of installation also, as the time required for install is unpredictable, it depends upon the processor speed and memory available. please help me, I had tried installing pip and pywinauto module, but one by one python shell window is asking new modules to be missing.

Comment: Can you provide concrete examples? It will make your question more clear. When we have the package to reproduce your problem, it's much easier to help. Consider any question on StackOverflow as a detailed bug report. Too general questions are not recommended.

Comment: >> `I had tried installing pip and pywinauto module, but one by one python shell window is asking new modules to be missing.` What is the output from your shell window? Please copy-paste it into the question.